# PiVPN connection succeeds and then is immediately cut off

Tags: networking, server, network-manager, vpn, openvpn

I'm looking to run a VPN off my home server, and a friend recommended I use PiVPN, even though I'm running it off Debian 9, because its easy to set up. I install it to connect over TCP (intentional decision, I'm trying to get around a workplace proxy) and make sure that everything is configured properly, static IP and everything. When I try to connect using the .ovpn file it gives me (through Ubuntu 19.04's Network Manager), it fails to connect due to a time-out. This seems odd to me (I'm testing it at my neighbour's house) so I check /var/log/syslog:

```
Oct 29 21:34:27 Archimedes nm-openvpn[28489]: OpenVPN 2.4.6 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [LZ4] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [MH/PKTINFO] [AEAD] built on May 14 2019
Oct 29 21:34:27 Archimedes nm-openvpn[28489]: library versions: OpenSSL 1.1.1b  26 Feb 2019, LZO 2.10
Oct 29 21:34:27 Archimedes nm-openvpn[28489]: NOTE: the current --script-security setting may allow this configuration to call user-defined scripts
Oct 29 21:34:28 Archimedes nm-openvpn[28489]: TCP/UDP: Preserving recently used remote address: [AF_INET]xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443
Oct 29 21:34:28 Archimedes nm-openvpn[28489]: Attempting to establish TCP connection with [AF_INET]xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443 [nonblock]
Oct 29 21:34:30 Archimedes nm-openvpn[28489]: TCP connection established with [AF_INET]xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443
Oct 29 21:34:30 Archimedes nm-openvpn[28489]: TCP_CLIENT link local: (not bound)
Oct 29 21:34:30 Archimedes nm-openvpn[28489]: TCP_CLIENT link remote: [AF_INET]xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443
Oct 29 21:34:30 Archimedes nm-openvpn[28489]: NOTE: chroot will be delayed because of --client, --pull, or --up-delay
Oct 29 21:34:30 Archimedes nm-openvpn[28489]: NOTE: UID/GID downgrade will be delayed because of --client, --pull, or --up-delay
Oct 29 21:34:31 Archimedes nm-openvpn[28489]: Connection reset, restarting [0]
Oct 29 21:34:31 Archimedes nm-openvpn[28489]: SIGUSR1[soft,connection-reset] received, process restarting
Oct 29 21:34:36 Archimedes nm-openvpn[28489]: NOTE: the current --script-security setting may allow this configuration to call user-defined scripts
Oct 29 21:34:36 Archimedes nm-openvpn[28489]: TCP/UDP: Preserving recently used remote address: [AF_INET]xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443
Oct 29 21:34:36 Archimedes nm-openvpn[28489]: Attempting to establish TCP connection with [AF_INET]xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443 [nonblock]
Oct 29 21:34:37 Archimedes nm-openvpn[28489]: TCP connection established with [AF_INET]xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443
Oct 29 21:34:37 Archimedes nm-openvpn[28489]: TCP_CLIENT link local: (not bound)
Oct 29 21:34:37 Archimedes nm-openvpn[28489]: TCP_CLIENT link remote: [AF_INET]xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443
Oct 29 21:34:37 Archimedes nm-openvpn[28489]: Connection reset, restarting [0]
Oct 29 21:34:37 Archimedes nm-openvpn[28489]: SIGUSR1[soft,connection-reset] received, process restarting
```

which repeated several times, and ended with

```
Oct 29 21:35:27 Archimedes NetworkManager[1218]: <warn>  [1572399327.6425] vpn-connection[0x55ad1824c700,91094ad9-b7ac-4022-928e-6a286ffe18ef,"plato-Archimedes",0]: VPN connection: connect timeout exceeded.
Oct 29 21:35:27 Archimedes nm-openvpn-serv[28486]: Connect timer expired, disconnecting.
Oct 29 21:35:27 Archimedes nm-openvpn[28489]: SIGTERM[hard,init_instance] received, process exiting
Oct 29 21:35:27 Archimedes NetworkManager[1218]: <warn>  [1572399327.6513] vpn-connection[0x55ad1824c700,91094ad9-b7ac-4022-928e-6a286ffe18ef,"plato-Archimedes",0]: VPN plugin: failed: connect-failed (1)
Oct 29 21:35:27 Archimedes NetworkManager[1218]: <info>  [1572399327.6514] vpn-connection[0x55ad1824c700,91094ad9-b7ac-4022-928e-6a286ffe18ef,"plato-Archimedes",0]: VPN plugin: state changed: stopping (5)
Oct 29 21:35:27 Archimedes NetworkManager[1218]: <info>  [1572399327.6514] vpn-connection[0x55ad1824c700,91094ad9-b7ac-4022-928e-6a286ffe18ef,"plato-Archimedes",0]: VPN plugin: state changed: stopped (6)
```

I thought perhaps it was a firewall issue (I may be way off the mark here - I'm somewhat new to Linux and networking) so I checked /var/log/ufw.log on the serverside, which contained just one line:

```
Oct 29 21:21:45 plato-debian kernel: [ 1752.752849] [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp3s0 OUT= MAC=33:33:00:00:00:01:48:45:20:8f:e4:ef:86:dd SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:9526:95e6:224a:04d7 DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 LEN=229 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=1 FLOWLBL=862228 PROTO=UDP SPT=27036 DPT=27036 LEN=189
```

I note that the SRC block looks like an IPv6 address, while I was under the impression that I was trying to connect using IPv4. Even so, the firewall should let me through.

Does anyone know how to fix this, or if not, at least what's going wrong?

Comment: I'm new to posting here, and welcome criticisms and edit suggestions to my questions (as I know badly-formatted questions can be infuriating to read and just not worth anyone's time)

Comment: For the start if you're using a firewall then turn it off and reload network and try to connect if it succeeds then the issue is with firewall.

Comment: @JoKeR Tried disabling the firewall, to no avail. The same output is printed.